# Can't build Android platform in Cordova 5.0.0 with build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

My enviroment is Windows 7 + Visual studio 2013 to develop hybrid mobile app,
After i upgrade Cordova to 5.0.0, i've already upgrade SDK to newly version, and eliminable  Command failed with exit code 2, then deploy to Device and build with Android, i got the compile error:

```
Error 1 E:\@Project\Mobile\Apps\BlankProject\BlankProject\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8  
E:\@Project\Mobile\Apps\BlankProject\BlankProject\MDAVSCLI  1 1 BlankProject
```

it seen to Command failed with exit code 2 become 8, am i missed anything else?

============================================================

Edited:

The reason why i have tested as below:

1.) Upgrade     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\0d2pwvj3.s0k\packages\vs-mda\package.json >> cordova version from 4.3.0 to 5.0.0, then the error will happed.

2.) Reverse step 1 with cordova version from 5.0.0 to 4.3.0, and to be normal.

So, Cordova 5.0.0 with Visual Studio 2013 means to me should not work.

Comment: Please show full error message.

Comment: Sorry, Here's the full error message: Error 1 E:\@Project\Mobile\Apps\BlankProject\BlankProject\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8  
E:\@Project\Mobile\Apps\BlankProject\BlankProject\MDAVSCLI  1 1 BlankProject

Comment: Are you building this with visual studio 2013?

Comment: @AlanYao Exactly, building this with visual studio 2013 with Cordova 5.0.0

Comment: are you able to do a cordova cli build? open cmd  and cd to the root folder. The do: > cordova build android  < and see whether you get more detailed output

Comment: @avvi Nope, the cordova 5.0.0 incompatible with VS2013, So I switch to VS2015. VS2015 could change taco.json to switch cordova version. Thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find somebody using visual studio cordova!  I've just migrated to Visual Studio Community 2015 RC from Visual Studio 2013 Community.

When you install 2015, you don't have to uninstall 2013, they can co-exist.  But migration of cordova project should be done manually by opening a new project, add plugin and copy contents from old index.html.

2013 cordova is going to be deprecated, try the new 5.0.0 in 2015.  And pls. let me know if it can be upgraded.  I guess you may have better chance in 2015!  By the way, why do you need 500?  what specific tasks you can't do with 430?

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, it's good to know vs2013 probably don't support corvoda 5.0.0. I'm using vs2013 community with cordova 4.3.0 for development, it's a great tool for developing cordova. There's no reason for me to upgrade to cordova 5.0.0, i'm just wanna to test the new thing. And also, i found the related information from here [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-known-issues-vs.aspx). ya, it's hard to find somebody use the same tool.